# How does adding and subtracting affect register states in a GameBoy?

Tags: emulation, gameboy

I am currently developing a GameBoy emulator. While coding I started to question how adding to a register affects it.

There are eight 8 bit registers and four 16 bit registers on the cpu. The 8 bit registers can be combined to form 16 bit registers. Here is how I have represented them in code.

```
struct Registers{
    //8 bit registers
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d;
    uint8_t e;
    uint8_t f;
    uint8_t h;
    uint8_t l;
    //16 bit registers
    uint16_t af;
    uint16_t bc;
    uint16_t de;
    uint16_t hl;
};
```

QUESTIONS:

1. If a lower register has the value of 0b11111111 and I add 1 to it. Does that bit carry on to the higher register, or does it wrap around to the beginning of the lower 8 bit register.
2. If a low register has the value of 0b00000000 and I sub 1 from it, Does it remain zero, or does that bit wrap to the top of the register.
3. If a high register has the value of 0b00000000 and I sub 1 from it, does it affect the lower register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, I don't think your way of organizing the registers is a good one, since you have duplicated information (storing both a, f and af). One option would be to use unions; unions ensure that two variables share the same memory location. So, you could do:

```
struct Registers{
    union{
        struct{
            uint_8t f;
            uint_8t a;
        };
        uint_16t af;
    };
    // And so on for the rest...
};
```

This way you can manipulate each of the 8bit registers individually (registers.a) or both at the same time (registers.af). Note that if you are developing in a big endian machine, f and a should be swapped to ensure the correct endianness.

If your compiler doesn't support anonymous structs and unions, i think a better option would be to make a function that manipulates the two 8 bit registers and shifts them to form a 16bit register. This way you don't have to access both a and af every time you modify them.

Now to your actual question. My information is based both from [this table](http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html) (which contains some errors i've been told, so better to look at other sources to confirm them), and [this manual](http://marc.rawer.de/Gameboy/Docs/GBCPUman.pdf).

Question 1:
No, it doesn't carry to the higher register, it will overflow.

Question 2:
Same thing, it wraps to 0xFF.

Question 3:
Assuming you are using 8 bit ALU operations, then no, again it doesn't affect it.

Note that if you are using 16 bit ALU operations, then they would affect the other register. For example:

Assuming SP = 0x00FF;

```
ADD SP, 0x1 #Now SP does contain 0x0100 because you used 16 bit arithmetic.
```

However:

Assuming HL = 0x00FF;

```
ADD L, 1 # L Overflows to 0x00, however HL = 0x0000 because you used 8 bit arithmetic
```

Comment: Thx so much. That is the exact answer I was looking for. I had thought of using a union inside a struct but decided against. I will change it tho. Thx

Comment: To be fair, this was not my idea, I'm not that smart, I would have used functions. I remembered this tip from [this guy](https://cturt.github.io/cinoop.html)